# WSO2 Class Mediator gives an error

Tags: class, wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

Our team is completely new to the WSO2 tool. We got the basic training on how to add proxy services and were able to do so as well.

Now, we have to add a class in the In Sequence. We tried that using the Class mediator but it was not able to find the class. Then we realized that the jar file needs to be in the `components/lib` folder. So, its able to load the class now. It proceeds to the out sequence and fault sequence properly. But, in the end, it gives the following exception.

```
Unable to add proxy service :: Failed to add proxy service: Parse. Check whether the Proxy already exists-Failed to add proxy service: Parse. Check whether the Proxy already exists
```

So far, we're using the design view to configure it. I surveyed through most of the posts within this forum, and, all are using the source code to configure. Also, the proxy service is not present in the Source View section under Service Bus.

**Are we missing any step in the configuration?** Do we need to switch to coding method or it is possible this way.

Comment: what type of proxy you were trying to add? I believe that you are able to create the sequences successively, but failing to add a proxy. At which point you faced the above issue? when pointing sequences for that proxy or at final stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is strange. Above mentioned error log can appear at the time of deploying the proxy service. But you say your proxy is going to the out-sequence and fault-sequence. From that what I understand is the proxy is already deployed.

You can check whether a proxy with the same name is there by looking in the ESB_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-config/default/proxy-service folder. If there is a file with name Parse.xml (I think the name of the proxy service is Parse) you can delete it from the file system and then go to the design view and add the proxy again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is already a proxy with the name you provided. Go to WSO2 ESB "source view" and check whether there exist a proxy with that name. Source view is available on the left side of the management console.

[This artical](http://wso2.org/library/2898) will take you step by step in writing custom class mediators.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152883/wso2-esb-add-class-mediator-to-proxy-service) may also be relevant for you.

Comment: Thank you all. I was able to solve it. I created a whole new class and proxy service and this time it went through. By the way, I got the error at the final stage of deployment.